# Query Azure AD Graph for B2C SignInName

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

How do I query Azure AD Graph for a [`SignInName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#signinname-type)? i.e. I want to take the user's login-name and find the user object in the Azure AD Graph.

---

I would assume I'm supposed to use [`$filter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options#filter), right?

I tried: `https://graph.windows.net/myB2Ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=signInNames eq spottedmahn`

and I got:

> The operand for a binary operator 'Equal' is not a single value. Binary operators require 
>   both operands to be single values.

---

Ok, so maybe I'm suppoed to use the `any` operator so then I tried: `https://graph.windows.net/myB2Ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=signInNames/any(c:c eq 'spottedmahn')`

> A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 
>   'Microsoft.DirectoryServices.SignlnName' and 'Edm.String' for operator kind 'Equal'.

---

Thinking that `c:c` is a lambda I then tried: `https://graph.windows.net/myB2Ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=signInNames/any(c:c.value eq 'spottedmahn')`

> The child type 'c.value' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types.

Reference: [User Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close.

You must filter by the `signInNames` array and match by the `value` property of each array item:

`https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=signInNames/any(x:x/value eq '{emailAddressOrUserName}')`