# Azure AD B2C .Net SDK - Retrieve User by Email

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to look up a user by sign-in email on our Azure AD B2C Tenant using the [C# .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=CS) and the filter described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49661768/284743), like so:

```
        private async Task<User> GetB2CUserByEmail(string email)
        {
            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage collectionPage = await this.GraphServiceClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Filter($"signInNames/any(c:c/value eq '{email}')")
                .Select(this.UserSelectValue)
                .GetAsync();

            if (collectionPage == null || collectionPage.Count == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return collectionPage[0];
        }
```

I'm getting the error:

```
 Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: BadRequest
    Message: Filter not supported.
```

Where `this.UserSelectValue` is a property selection list like `"id,givenName..."`. I've confirmed that's not the issue because we have a similar working method that looks up a user by an extension property; the only difference is the `.Filter()` parameter.

How can I make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a `signInNames` property in [user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties). That's the reason you get this error.

You should use `.Filter("identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '{email}' and c/issuer eq '{email}')")`.

See details from the official sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-find-a-user-account-using-a-sign-in-name).

Comment: That did the trick! MS, if you're reading...I've come across at least three different variations of this question. The current, right way to do it ought to be more discoverable in the B2C SDK docs.